# Python: How to verify data in a list is downward or upward trend

Tags: python, list

Without depending on external modules like numpy or pandas, is there any basic and simply python way to determine each column of follow example data, whether they are Upward, Constant or Downward

### Input data:

```
-Column1--Column2--Column3--Column4-
98394112 78677690 20070400 134579200
98418688 78684002 20070400 134554624
98418688 78692194 20070400 134554624
98443264 78708578 20070400 134530048
98443264 78724962 20070400 134530048
98467840 78733154 20070400 134505472
98467840 78749538 20070400 134505472
98516992 78774114 20070400 134456320
98516992 78798690 20070400 134456320
98566144 78831458 20070400 134407168
98615296 78864226 20070400 134358016
98615296 78888802 20070400 134358016
```

### Expected output:

```
Column1: Upward
Column2: Upward
Column3: Constant
Column4: Downward
```

Comment: How are these columns of data stored ? Are they lists ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example with the last column:

```
lst=[134579200,134554624,134554624,134530048,134530048,134505472,134505472,134456320,134456320,134407168,134358016,134358016]

sorted_lst=sorted(lst)

if(sorted_lst==sorted_lst[::-1]):
    print("Constant")
    
elif(lst==sorted_lst):
    print("Upward")

elif(lst==sorted_lst[::-1]):
    print("Downward")
```

[**Output**]

```
Downward
```

Comment: Thank you AziMez, for sharing great thought. It was very useful. I could able to proceed with my work. Thanks a lot. Though I have not show in my initial example, some data like this behaving bit differently - [107944200, 107913220, 107882770, 107851800, 107831320, 107810850, 107769900, 107718970, 107728950, 107698500, 107667520, 107626570, 107534700, 107565150]